# Turn my function into a constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I am basically doing one of the Kata javascript problems and I have managed to get a function that does the job, apart from it doesn't work as a constructor function and I'm afraid I'm now a bit lost.

I need to make it so that the below code works with a supplied string IE

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
  function accum(){
  var boom = s.split("");
  count = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < boom.length; i++) {
    repeat = count++;
    finalvalue = boom[i].repeat(repeat);
    var capitalizeLetter = finalvalue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
      finalvalue.slice(1);
    console.log(capitalizeLetter);
  }
  }

  accum('opportunity');
```

**Output**

O
Pp
Ppp
Oooo
Rrrrr
Tttttt
Uuuuuuu
Nnnnnnnn
Iiiiiiiii
Tttttttttt
Yyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: What do you mean by 'constructor function' ?

Comment: basically it needs to be a function that can take any value so i would have the function accum(); and in that I could put a value and it would run the function on that value

Comment: What do you want to construct, and how will it be used?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. `function('this is a string');` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is just called a regular `function`. A constructor is used with classes so it would appear to be inapplicable here.

Just wrap it like so:

```js
function myFunction(s) {
  let boom = s.split("");
  count = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < boom.length; i++) {
    repeat = count++;
    finalvalue = boom[i].repeat(repeat);
    let capitalizeLetter = finalvalue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
      finalvalue.slice(1);
    console.log(capitalizeLetter);
  }
}

myFunction("opportunity");
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I hope so! it's not working with the kata test system, just seems to return undefined, which I don't understand but will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

You want it to work when page is ready, like this?

```js
(function() {
   // your function 
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function f(s) {
        var boom = s.split("");
        count = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < boom.length; i++) {
            repeat = count++;
            finalvalue = boom[i].repeat(repeat);
            var capitalizeLetter = finalvalue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                finalvalue.slice(1);
            console.log(capitalizeLetter);
        }
    } 
f('this is a string');
```